# save the output to multiple files in crontab

Tags: linux, shell-script, cron

There is a script scheduled in crontab.

```
0 2 * * * /usr/local/bin/backup.sh >> /root/output_all.txt
```

I want to save the output into multiple files like output_all.txt and output_date.txt at the same time.

I know there is `tee` command to save the output to the multiple files.
But `tee` can be used only when tty exists?

Is there any other solution?

Comment: I'm asking ```tee``` command not ```tree```. Using Debian bullseye BTW. Thanks.

Comment: Typo  .... I meant `tee` ...

Answer (score 1):

Using `tee` works with no issues. `tty` is just the device that is used to interact with the operating system and is located at `/dev/tty#`.

```
0 2 * * * /usr/local/bin/backup.sh | tee /root/output_all.txt output_date.txt
```

If you want it to append the output to the files and and not overwrite what exists:

```
0 2 * * * /usr/local/bin/backup.sh | tee -a /root/output_all.txt output_date.txt
```

Keep in mind that the above methods will send to stdout and the files and email the cron user.

Comment: It may be worth noting that your example commands would save the output into the two files and also output it on standard output, which would generally result in an email to the owner of the crontab.

Comment: The standard method to send output to two files (without a spare copy going to the original stdout) would be `... | tee /root/output_all.txt >output_date.txt` (to replace the previous files) or `... | tee -a /root/output_all.txt >>output_date.txt` (to append).

Answer (score 0):

The process is generally agnostic of whether it runs by cron session or by terminal connected session, so your question should be only : "save output to multiple files", it is in fact the simpler aspect : use `tee` to fork the standard output to one or more files, don't forget that the remaining output goes to `sendmail` by default. If you don't want a growing unmanaged mailbox, consider piping with `|& logger`, a lazy option better than vanishing with `&>/dev/null` after having set `SHELL=/bin/bash` depending on the syntax you prefer.

That leads us back to the mistake you did : a cron initiated process is only missing `stdin` (it exists but is void, say `/dev/null`), `$DISPLAY` and other desktop specific resource that you understand intuitively as participating in user interface, including crypto agents that require an active user session ;  just try to schedule only tasks that don't need user interaction.

Seriously, with cronjobs, it's worth configure mail routing, because all remaining output is routed to mail instead of your terminal. That's all.

Comment: `&>` is a bashism, and probably won't work in a crontab entry; use `>/dev/null 2>&1` to discard output & errors reliably, or just `>/dev/null` if you want to discard normal output but not errors (discarding error output tends to be a bad idea, especially when troubleshooting).

Comment: you're all right, but realistically, where crontab is managed in a very lazy way, stderr stdout does not make sens either. There is a special policy for lazy box  where the good advice for well tight environments does not apply :) So to avoid storage saturation is less worse.